# SQL Server - Sum Sales between Dates That are both columns

Tags: sql-server, sum

Running into an issue here. Basically I have 2 tables, one with sales data and one with Salesforce opportunity data. The opportunity table has `Start Date` and `End Date` columns, and the sales table has a `Sales Date` column. The 2 tables are linked by the `Account Number`.

Basically I need to get a sum of Total Sales for each account where the Sales Date is between the Start and End Dates of the opportunity. The issue here being that the Start and End dates for each opportunity may not be the same.

Here's a simplified version of what I'm trying to get to:

Opportunity table:

```
Opportunity Account Start Date  End Date
Purina        x     4/1/2020    4/30/2020
Purina        y     4/4/2020    4/30/2020
Purina        z     4/10/2020   4/20/2020
```

Sales Table:

```
Sales   Account Sales Date
50         x    4/2/2020
50         x    4/15/2020
50         x    5/1/2020
50         y    4/2/2020
50         y    4/5/2020
50         y    4/15/2020
50         z    4/1/2020
50         z    4/15/2020
50         z    4/20/2020
```

Result:

```
Opportunity Account Sales
Purina         x    100
Purina         y    150
Purina         z    50
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far???

Comment: It would be good if u can provide sample , table structures, data, expected output and the query that you have tried .

Comment: Just edited my original post with a simplified example

Answer (score 0):

I don't have much insides but Maybe something like this would help You.

```
select 
    s.Account_Number, 
    count(*)
from sales s
join salesforce sf
on s.AccountNumber = sf.AccountNumber
where s.SalesDate between sf.Start_Date and sf.End_Date
group by 
    s.Account_Number
```